# How it is possible to put wordpress contact form into static html page?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, static

I have a static page uploaded to wordpress, how can I connect to particular static page contact form from plugin? Is it possible to do it through shortcode?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CF7 it's easy:

```
<?php echo apply_shortcodes( '[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]' ); >
```